# Absolutely positioned containing div to fit the inside content or viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a responsive panel navigation and I have a problem..
The problem is that I can’t get the containing div to fit the inside content if content is smaller than the viewport and to be 100% of the body/viewport if the viewport is smaller then the content inside and get a scroll.

Test 1 gets a scroll(good) when the content is bigger then the viewport
but the wrapper is 100% of the viewport when the content is smaller(bad, no clickability under that div and the button must stay under that div regarding z-index because i will have  a full screen map under)
Test 2 is vice versa.
I need a mix of those examples – for the wrapper to get a scroll if the viewport is smaller and fit the inside content if viewport is bigger.

Am I stupid or what – it seems to be a simple task

Test 1
wrapper height:100%; 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/esqxL

```
<button id="button">Click</button>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left-menu-top">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tristique laoreet dui, id porttitor ipsum convallis vel. Integer turpis nisl, rhoncus sed hendrerit sit amet, adipiscing nec eros. Suspendisse potenti. Nam quis risus libero. Vestibulum et diam nisl, eget feugiat leo. Quisque rutrum fermentum leo, sit amet semper eros elementum eu. Donec aliquam magna et sem condimentum rutrum. Sed augue nulla, rhoncus venenatis scelerisque sed, accumsan sed magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut quis felis dui.</p>

</div>
</div>

    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

body {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrapper {  
  padding:8px;
  width:340px;
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

}

#left-menu-top {
    width: auto;
    display:block;
}

#button {
    bottom:10px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Test 2
wrapper height:auto; 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yovkJ

```
<button id="button">Click</button>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-menu-top">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tristique laoreet dui, id porttitor ipsum convallis vel. Integer turpis nisl, rhoncus sed hendrerit sit amet, adipiscing nec eros. Suspendisse potenti. Nam quis risus libero. Vestibulum et diam nisl, eget feugiat leo. Quisque rutrum fermentum leo, sit amet semper eros elementum eu. Donec aliquam magna et sem condimentum rutrum. Sed augue nulla, rhoncus venenatis scelerisque sed, accumsan sed magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut quis felis dui.</p>

    </div>
</div>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

body {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrapper {  
  padding:8px;
  width:340px;
  height: auto;
  position:fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

}

#left-menu-top {
    width: auto;
    display:block;
}

#button {
    bottom:10px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Is it possible just with css or i need a bit of javascript?

Tnx

Comment: the "or" in your problem part of the question is confusing, i cant believe this question is edited and its still unreadable, if you are gonna edit, edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max-width` CSS property.

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmfua14o/2/)

`max-width: 100%` will limit the width to that of the parent container. `box-sizing` is set to `border-box` so it will take padding and borders into account when calculating the on-screen width of `wrapper`.

For more information about these properties, please check out:

- max-width http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp
- box-sizing http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

## Making it fit into content

If you know the width of your box, you can use the following media query:

```
@media (max-width: 340px) {
    #wrapper {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

What it does is that if the screen (window) is thinner than 340 pixels, the `position: static` CSS property is applied to the wrapper. If the media query is *after* the standard `#wrapper` definitions, it will overwrite. Else, use `!important`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to get an satisfacting result with height:auto; and max-height:calc(100% - 46px); because I needed that regarding the height. Is CSS calc function possible and valid in max-height property? The reason I discarded the height and max-height in my example because i had a custom scroll that did not resize on viewport height change.

Comment: JS-Fidle of my solution http://jsfiddle.net/h3827qwy/
Try resizing the height of the viewport

Comment: Yes, both `max-width` and `max-height` accepts the value of a CSS `calc()`. Don't forget, however, that `calc()` is a CSS3 expression, and not widely compatible with older browsers. See http://caniuse.com/#search=calc for more details.